# Can't update object in a service with spring boot and mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Currently, I created a spring controller rest and a spring service.

I send a string with Angular(Promise) to the controller and the controller calls the function update of the service.

Here is the code of the service :

```
@Service
public class LinkServiceImpl implements LinkService{

@Autowired
private  UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private ProfilRepository profilRepository;



public LinkServiceImpl() {

}


public void update( LinkWidget linkEntry) {
    for (Profil profil : profilRepository.findAll() ) {

       Profil updateProfil =  updateProfil(linkEntry, profilRepository.findOne(profil.getId()));
        profilRepository.save(updateProfil);

    }




}


public Profil updateProfil(LinkWidget linkEntry,Profil profil){

        for (Theme theme : profil.getListWidget()){


            List<LinkWidget> linksToRemove = new ArrayList<LinkWidget>() ;
            for (LinkWidget link : theme.getListLinkWidget()){

                    try{
                        if (link.getRefLink() != null) {
                        if (link.getRefLink().equals(linkEntry.getRefLink())) {

                            link.setUrl(linkEntry.getUrl());
                            link.setName(linkEntry.getName());
                            link.setImage(linkEntry.getImage());
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException n){

                    }


            }



        }

        return profil;


}




}
```

I get all profils in mongodb collection and after, with the parameter, I search to update the objects with the same ref and the profil at the end.

But the update is done time to time . When i get the profils after the update, sometimes it works sometines it doesn't work. I tried with @Transactional but this is not the philosophy of MongoDb. So my question is : Why the update doesn't work all the time? Maybe a problem with my code because there are a lot of tasks?

Comment: Also, it doesn't update all the objects with the same parameter(ref)